# Microphone permission gets asked right away when joining a channel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, agora.io

I am working on an app similar to skype. My problem is the following (only on iOS): when I join a meeting screen with JoinChannel() I have previously enabled audio with EnableVideo(). Because of that I get asked microphone permission on iOS right away, but I want to ask that permission only when the user taps the microphone button for the first time. Like I said, it only reproduces on iOS and if I try to DisableAudio() then it is not possible to hear what other uses are saying in the channel. Also, things like MuteLocalAudioStream() do not work. Any ideas? (JoinMeeting() is called in Awake())

```
 public void JoinMeeting(string meetingId, bool micOn, string userId, bool useProxy, Regions region, bool enableEncryption, string key,
  string salt)
{
  _remoteUserAudioEnableStatusCache.Clear();

  _userId = userId;
  _inMeeting = true;

  InitEngine(useProxy, region);

  if (enableEncryption && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
  {
    var encryptionConfig = new EncryptionConfig
    {
      encryptionMode = ENCRYPTION_MODE.AES_256_GCM2,
      encryptionKey = key,
      encryptionKdfSalt = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(salt) ? Convert.FromBase64String(salt) : null
    };

    _mRtcEngine.EnableEncryption(true, encryptionConfig).Log(_loggingModule);
  }

  _mRtcEngine.EnableAudio().Log(_loggingModule);
  _mRtcEngine.EnableVideo().Log(_loggingModule);
  _mRtcEngine.EnableVideoObserver().Log(_loggingModule);
  _mRtcEngine.SetExternalVideoSource(true).Log(_loggingModule);
  _mRtcEngine.JoinChannel(meetingId, null, Convert.ToUInt32(_userId)).Log(_loggingModule);

  IsMicMute = !micOn;
}
```

Comment: Please follow this site's tagging guidelines and avoid putting tags in your question titles.

Comment: Got it! First time mistake